# Changing variables in a series expansion

Tags: series-expansion, variable-definitions, algebraic-manipulation

I want to compute the Taylor expansion of some pure function `f[x_]`, but then perform a change of variables in the resulting expression.

So, for example, the output of

```
Series[f[x], {x, x0, 2}]
```

will be

```
f[x0] = (x - x0) f'[x0] + 1/2 (x - x0)^2 f''[x0] + O[x^3]
```

I want to make the change of variable `x = x0 + t`, so that the we have `x - x0 = t` and the resulting expression is

```
f[x0] = t f'[x0] + 1/2 t^2 f''[x0] + O[x^3]
```

I can't find a way to do this using `Simplify[]`, `Eliminate[]`, or anything else after converting the output to a normal expression with `Normal[]`.

Comment: `ComposeSeries[Series[f[x], {x, x0, 2}], t + x0 + O[t]^3]`?

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly.

Comment: If you understood what exactly happened in that snippet, I recommend trying to write an answer to your own question. :)

Comment: I just found that using `Series[f[x0 + t], {t, 0, 2}]` works equivalently.